# Determine joint occurences of row values in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset with the following structure:

```
dput(structure(foc[1:50]))
structure(list(firm_id = c("Texas", "Texas", "Texas", "Micron", 
"Micron", "DowCor", "DowCor", "DowCor", "DowCor", "DowCor", "DowCor", 
"Altera", "Altera", "Texas", "Texas", "Texas", "Molex", "Molex", 
"DowCor", "DowCor", "DowCor", "NSC", "NSC", "Micron", "Micron", 
"AAV", "AAV", "AAV", "AMD", "AMD", "DowCor", "DowCor", "Molex", 
"Molex", "Molex", "NSC", "NSC", "NSC", "Micron", "Micron", "CORN", 
"CORN", "DowCor", "DowCor", "Zilog", "Zilog", "CORN", "CORN", 
"CORN", "Micron"), pnum = c(5351876, 5351876, 5351876, 5362632, 
5362632, 5364633, 5364633, 5364633, 5364633, 5364633, 5364633, 
5369314, 5369314, 5370301, 5370301, 5370301, 5370551, 5370551, 
5371128, 5371128, 5371128, 5372410, 5372410, 5376577, 5376577, 
5383340, 5383340, 5383340, 5384272, 5384272, 5384383, 5384383, 
5384435, 5384435, 5384435, 5385861, 5385861, 5385861, 5387534, 
5387534, 5387558, 5387558, 5389365, 5389365, 5389565, 5389565, 
5392376, 5392376, 5392376, 5393694), date = structure(c(8769, 
8769, 8769, 8804, 8804, 8838, 8838, 8838, 8838, 8838, 8838, 8818, 
8818, 8769, 8769, 8769, 8772, 8772, 8779, 8779, 8779, 8798, 8798, 
8946, 8946, 8848, 8848, 8848, 8944, 8944, 8796, 8796, 8793, 8793, 
8793, 8839, 8839, 8839, 8890, 8890, 8887, 8887, 8803, 8803, 8772, 
8772, 8866, 8866, 8866, 8931), class = "Date"), PRIM = c("228", 
"257", "269", "257", "438", "264", "424", "428", "514", "521", 
"977", "326", "714", "228", "257", "269", "220", "439", "424", 
"427", "524", "188", "303", "257", "438", "257", "361", "62", 
"257", "438", "528", "556", "174", "361", "439", "148", "257", 
"438", "257", "438", "106", "501", "424", "528", "257", "438", 
"385", "428", "501", "257"), N = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L)), .Names = c("firm_id", 
"pnum", "date", "PRIM", "N"), sorted = "pnum", class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000140788>)
```

It looks pretty much like this:

```
foc
       firm_id    pnum       date PRIM N
    1:   Texas 5351876 1994-01-04  228 3
    2:   Texas 5351876 1994-01-04  257 3
    3:   Texas 5351876 1994-01-04  269 3
    4:  Micron 5362632 1994-02-08  257 2
    5:  Micron 5362632 1994-02-08  438 2
   ---                                  
91731:   Intel 7472285 2003-06-25  713 3
91732:   Intel 7472289 2004-12-21  381 2
91733:   Intel 7472289 2004-12-21  713 2
91734:   Intel 7472390 2003-10-01  712 2
91735:   Intel 7472390 2003-10-01  718 2
```

I have a larger data.table called `df` of which the above is a subset. Specifically, the above starts in 1994 and the dataset `df` goes back until 1980. The names in `df` are identical except that, for clarity, the `PRIM` column from `foc` is called `prim` in the `df` data.table.

I want to identify the occurrence of pairs of PRIM in the bigger dataset. Pairs exist when two PRIM occur jointly with the same pnum. No two identical PRIM can occur with the same pnum and every pnum in dataset has between 2 and 8 PRIM.
In addition, I want to impose a time limit, by using "date", i.e. I only want to consider pnum that are less than 5 years old.

For instance, the first pnum in the above data = 5351876. It has three distinct PRIM and thus three pairs (228,257), (228, 269), and (257, 269). In the data.table example there is one pnum that has 6 different PRIM so that one will have 15 different pairs. Note that the order of a pair is irrelevant, so (228, 257) = (257, 228).

The code below does something simple that I need as well. It counts the number of times each PRIM appears in the 5 year before but I am not sure how to determine the frequency with which specific pairs occur.

```
findpairs <- data.table()
findpairs <- data.table(rbind(findpairs, foc[, {print(.GRP) ; k = pnum ; p = PRIM ; y = unique(date)
                                        df[(date < y & date > (y - (5*365 + 1)) & p == prim), .N]}
                                          , by = .(pnum, PRIM)]))
```

Any suggestions are very welcome

PS: In a second stage I will want to be able to include two "firm_id" conditions as well: Exclude focal firm_id or only look at one firm_id. That's why this variable is kept in the data.table at the moment but not used.

EDIT 1: Following on the first attempted answer I should clarify the desired output. There might be a more optimal solution that generates a distinct output but this is what I think would be awesome:
A data table that has 5 columns: `pnum`, `date` (the date of the pnum), `prim`, `paired prim`, and `pair incidence in 5y before date`. Remember a pair is agnostic about which `prim` comes first and a pair only exists when two PRIM values are found in the `df` data.table within the same `pnum`.

Hope this clarifies!
The function below

Answer (score 0):

Here's on solution that I came up with. You can use the following function to create the combinations.

```
make_prim_pairs <- function(values,n=2){
  combinations <- (apply(t(combn(values,min(n,length(values)))),1,paste,collapse=","))
  return(combinations)
}
```

So, if you want to find the pairs for entire data set then:

```
findpairs <- foc[,.(primPairs = make_prim_pairs(prim)),by=pnum]
```

That should find all the pairs by pnum. You can add conditions to the data and make the pairs as well.

```
y <- some_date
findpairs <- foc[date < y & date > (y - (5*365 + 1)),.(primPairs = make_prim_pairs(prim)),by=pnum]
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this suggestion. I will have to implement it at work to see what exactly is the result so i'm not 100% sure if this comment will make sense but does this function count the number of occurrences of pairs or just identify them? I don't know what the `combn` function does exactly which is why I am asking. Will try later and get back to you! Thanks for the help already :)

Comment: Hi again, I am at the office and the function you suggest does not seem to work or at least it does not provide me with a result I can interpret. I update the question with a desired output which hopefully will help in clarifying what I hope to get.

Comment: @SJDS If you can provide a glimpse of how the final output should look like (by manually creating one) then that would be really helpful as I am still struggling to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works quite well for small datasets but has now been running on a larger dataset for over 18 hours. No idea how close it is to finishing but I thought I'd share the solution. Maybe someone can make sense of it and improve it.

```
# Create all possible distinct pairs of prim classes that exist in the dataset df
setkey(df, pnum)
a <- df[df, allow.cartesian = T] # cartesion join to combine all possible pairs
a <- a[a$prim != a$i.prim] # delete pairs consisting of the same prim values 
a[, idx:= .I] # add index
a$pair <- a[,paste0(min(prim, i.prim),"_",max(prim, i.prim)),by = idx][[2]] # create pairs based on a single logic:1_2 must be same as 2_1
DT1 <- a[, .N, by = .(firm_id, pnum, date, pair)] # this is to delete the repeated pairs 
rm(a)

# Create all possible distinct pairs of prim classes that exist in the subset foc
setkey(foc, pnum)
a <- foc[foc, allow.cartesian = T] # cartesion join to combine all possible pairs
a <- a[a$PRIM != a$i.PRIM] # delete pairs consisting of the same prim values 
a[, idx:= .I] # add index
a$pair <- a[,paste0(min(PRIM, i.PRIM),"_",max(PRIM, i.PRIM)),by = idx][[2]] # create pairs based on a single logic:1_2 must be same as 2_1
DT2 <- a[, .N, by = .(firm_id, pnum, date, pair)] # this is to delete the repeated pairs 

rm(a)
DT1[, N:= NULL] ; DT2[, N:= NULL] # unwanted columns

setnames(DT2, "pair", "PAIR") # only for clarity purposes in the formula below. This is the post 1994 data set. 

couples <- data.table()
couples <- data.table(rbind(couples, DT2[, {k = pnum ; p = PAIR ; y = unique(date)
                                        DT1[(date < y & date > (y - (5*365 + 1)) & p == pair), .N]}
                                          , by = .(pnum, PAIR)]))
```

# This formula gives - I think - the number of times a unique pair appears in the previous 5 years.

```
couples$lowp <- sub("_.+","", couples$PAIR)   # split up the pair 
couples$highp <- sub(".+_","", couples$PAIR)  # split up the pair
```

That does the trick. The next steps are then to match the number of times the lowp and highp appear in the database (via findpairs in the OP) which is accomplished simply with match and to calculate the desired variable

```
coup <- couples
coup$n_lowp <- counts$n_p[match(paste(coup$pnum,"",coup$lowp), paste(counts$pnum,"",counts$PRIM))]
coup$n_highp <- counts$n_p[match(paste(coup$pnum,"",coup$highp), paste(counts$pnum,"",counts$PRIM))]

coup$yaya <- with(coup, n_pairs / (n_lowp + n_highp - n_pairs))
```

I'm sure there are much more effective ways but it works (slowly).